# Porting a C array declaration to Delphi

Tags: delphi

In C, I can declare and initialize an char array like this:

```
char arg[10] = "ANY";
```

Is there any short syntax to do the same in delphi?

Comment: You don't typically use C strings in Delphi unless doing interop. You normally just use Delphi strings. Why would you want a character array in Delphi?

Comment: It sounds like the OP is trying to translate his knowledge of K&R C into Delphi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A constant:

```
const
  arg: array[0 .. 9] of AnsiChar = 'ANY';
```

A local variable:

```
var
  arg: array[0 .. 9] of AnsiChar;
...
  arg := 'ANY';
```

A global variable:

```
var
  arg: array[0 .. 9] of AnsiChar = 'ANY';
```

Comment: Opps, my fault. It works, I've used PAnsichar instead of Ansichar :)

Comment: People should be aware that this code is intentionally creating an  array of AnsiChar, which would be an unusual thing to do. In a unicode delphi application that doesn't have to have some string 'ANY' be ansi, you would normally declare just const arg = 'ANY'. (Unicode string constant).

Answer (score -1):

something like this:

var
  arg1: string = 'any';

or

var arg2: packed array[0..9] of char = 'any';

if you really want an array starting with index 0, as in C, or

var arg3: pchar = 'any';

if you want a \0 terminated string