# C char type to delphi conversion

Tags: c, delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Porting a C array declaration to Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139867/porting-a-c-array-declaration-to-delphi)

I'm converting a C code to Delphi, and I want to convert a variable declaration, but I really don't know.. Can you help?

```
char szImageName[BUFMAXLEN];
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delphi equivalent is:

```
var
  szImageName: array [0..BUFMAXLEN-1] of AnsiChar;
```

Take care to use `AnsiChar` rather than `Char` since in modern versions of Delphi the generic type `Char` is aliased to the 2 byte `WideChar`. Of course if you are on pre-Unicode Delphi then this warning is not pertinent.

The biggest difference in the syntax is that all arrays in C have 0 as the lower bound. In Delphi you can specify whatever lower-bound you wish. Naturally to match the C code we specify 0 as our lower-bound.

Comment: Hi David, thank you.
But I'm with a problem, BUFMAXLEN is not defined in the code I'm trying to convert.. do you know how can I define it? thanks

Comment: It's defined in one of the header files that are included with #include

Comment: See: http://www.gamedeception.net/threads/5012-Module-Hiding

Comment: Without wishing to be rude, but your knowledge of C is probably not sufficient for you to attempt a port of that code. That code is pretty gnarly. I believe I answered the question you asked. I won't port this code for you.

Comment: Thanks David, I found a unit in Delphi! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
szImageName: array[0..BUFMAXLEN-1] of AnsiChar;
```