# Convert a declaration in C to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, char, declaration

How is this C code converted to delphi?

```
static unsigned char tempbuf[128*1024];
```

Thanks

Comment: `tempbuf: array [0..128*1024-1] of byte;`    am I correct?

Comment: You asked the same question a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933940/c-char-type-to-delphi-conversion

Comment: Only close, @Remy? Looks right to me. What's wrong with Paulohr's code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array itself is declared like this in Delphi:

```
tempbuf: array[0..(128*1024)-1] of Byte;
```

Regarding the `static` portion - that depends on where the array is declared.  If it is declared in global memory, then you don't need to declare it as `static` in Delphi, just put it in a global `var` section:

```
unit ...;

interface

var
  tempbuf: array[0..(128*1024)-1] of Byte; 

...

implementation

...

end.
```

Or:

```
unit ...;

interface

...

implementation

var
  tempbuf: array[0..(128*1024)-1] of Byte; 

...

end.
```

Depending on whether the array needs to be accessible to other units or not.

On the other hand, if the array is a member of a class/struct instead, then declare it as a `class var` in Delphi:

```
type
  TSomeClass = class
  class var
    tempbuf: array[0..(128*1024)-1] of Byte; 
  end;
```